# Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit ListPicker throws XamlParseException

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-toolkit, xamlparseexception, listpicker

After being advised that the native `ComboBox` was not the way to go I was told to look at the Silverlight Toolkit `ListPicker`. So I did and have got a problem.

I opened a new project and pulled a new `ListPicker` onto the MainPage. The `ListPicker` looks like:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Result">
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Win" />
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Place" />
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Lose" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

When trying to run this I get an `XamlParseException` with InnerException of `InvalidProgramException`. All I did was drag the control on, and add some `ListPickerItem`. Removing the items still results in the error, removing the `ListPicker` control completely allows the page to be shown with no error.

I'm sure I've missed something, but any documentation I have read seems to point towards this markup being fine, including http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth

I can provide any other info required.

Comment: Make sure that your page declaration includes the "toolkit" namespace

Comment: Yeah it does `xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"` without it, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Can you bind it to data from code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the wrong dlls had been registered, i.e. 7 and not 7.1. I had to uninstall and reinstall to get it to update correctly and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`ListPickerItem` is a class used internally by the `ListPicker` and should not be used directly.

If you just want to add a list of items, you can use strings to do it, like this:

Add a new namespace on top of the Page to access the `String` class:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then, just change the `ListPicker` code to this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker>
    <sys:String>Win</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Place</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Lose</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Comment: I tried using `String` but it didn't work, actually the problem was that I had previously installed 7.1 SDK but the DLLs didn't register properly, they were still the 7 dlls. I tried updating again and still the wrong dlls. So I completely uninstalled and reinstalled, updated and got the correct dlls. After this the `ListPickerItem` worked. But for handiness sake I used `String` anyway.